# How do I actually do/contribute to a Squad Mission?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Occasionally on the bottom right of the screen a Squad Mission prompt shows up with 5 what I assume are monster Icons. How do I go about accepting this mission, or if acceptance is not required, just contributing to it?

It looks like it is just a mission to kill certain monster classes/types but there doesn't seem to be any way of knowing what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to know what they are, it seems like they generally conform to a certain monster type (forfex, for example), so you can hunt that type of monster in the world and it will contribute.

The easiest way that I've found to kill them was to look for monsters with the `S` tag to the left of their name -- this means it's a target for a squad mission. Just kill those monsters until the number hits 0.

Comment: I don't remember the exact button combination, but I believe holding the L button and pressing R will let you cycle through the squad mission objectives when they're active. Sometimes the targets are gathered items.

Comment: @twobugs It's holding R and pressing L. Xenoblade is one of those games where you really, really need to read the manual because the game doesn't directly tell you most of this stuff. :P

Answer (score 0):

To view what each task specifically wants you to do, hold the "R" button, then tap the "L" button. Keep tapping "L" to cycle through the five tasks.